# Resource Path Location - Maven Java EE Configuration OSX

Tags: java, maven, configuration

I have changed compliance level to 1.7 and JRE to 1.7 but the problem is still there.

Resource Path Location Type Dynamic Web Module 3.0 requires Java 1.6 or newer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found [this](http://qussay.com/2013/09/13/solving-dynamic-web-module-3-0-requires-java-1-6-or-newer-in-maven-projects/), i hope it's useful.

Navigate to eclipse Preferences > Java > Installed JREs, click Add, and locate your installed Java path.

Open your project’s pom.xml and add this plugin tag.

```
   <build>
     <plugins>
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
         <configuration>
              <source>1.7</source>
              <target>1.7</target>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```